# Shopware 6 send multiple objects over one API Call

Tags: shopware

I wrote a script that updates one product after another in my Shopware 6 system using its API. (Each product is updated with a separate API call.)

This is super slow and not really performant, so I tried to send multiple products as a collection using one call. Sadly this doesn't seem to work with Shopware 6.

Does anyone know if and how to send multiple product objects using one API call only?

What I currently have, roughly looks like this:

```
$product = [
    "id" = 1, "someData" = "someData"
];
callApi($products);
$product = [
    "id" = 2, "someData" = "someData2"
];
callApi($products);
$product = [
    "id" = 3, "someData" = "someData3"
];
callApi($products);
```

From some experience with other systems you can mostly create a multi-object like this:

```
$products = [
    ["id" = 1, "someData" = "someData"],
    ["id" = 2, "someData" = "someData2"],
    ["id" = 3, "someData" = "someData3"]
]
callApi($products);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For use cases like this a special `/sync` endpoint exist that may be used for bulk operations.

Please refer to the [official api documentation](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTUx-bulk-payloads).

Comment: That works well for me.
Thanks a lot